# Simple Class with Constructor throws an warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c++, class, constructor

So I'm building a Regex class, with a simple constructor:

regex.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef REGEX_CUSTOM_CLASS
#define REGEX_CUSTOM_CLASS

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Regex
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    char *regex;

    Regex(char str[]);
};

#endif  // REGEX_CUSTOM_CLASS
```

regex.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "regex.hpp"

using namespace std;


Regex::Regex(char str[])
{
    regex = str;
}
```

tools.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "lib/regex/regex.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Regex my_regex("//");

    cout << my_regex.regex << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But after I compile it to .exe file and run it, I get this error message:
`warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' Regex my_regex("//");`

I think the problem is with the data types. What is the problem?

Comment: The error message is correct to use `"//"` you need have the functiin gave a  `const char*` parameter.

Comment: @WebTools -- The `"\\"` is not a `char *`.  It is a `const char *`.

Comment: A note on the duplicate: The message has changed a bit and the result is now a hard error instead of the warning used to let people know that the transition to making it an error was underway, but the mechanics are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass arrays by value. When you write:

```
Regex::Regex(char str[])
```

this actually is

```
Regex::Regex(char* str)
```

Moreover string literals are of type `const char [N]` (where `N` is length of the string including the null terminator) and when passed to functions they decay to `const char*`. Getting a `char*` from a `const char*` (pointer to constant `char`, not to be confused with constant pointer to `char`) would break const correctness.

Either use `std::string` as argument type or change it to `const char*`.